# Return custom object with exception details on exception in .net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to return custom object with error details when exception occurs

`EmployeeDetails` class has property with `ErrorDetails`.

In case of Success `EmployeeDetails` object will be returned. When exception occurs i want to populate `ErrorDetails` property and return `EmployeeDetails` object.

Each Action Method as it's own Return Type. All the return types will have `ErrorDetails` property.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<EmployeeDetails>> LoanClosingDateUpdate()
{

}
```

I tried adding `ProducesResponseType` on each action but it did not work. 
`[ProducesResponseType(typeof(EmployeeDetails), (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]`

Can i handle it globally either from OnException filter or Middleware

Comment: You controller method should return `Task<IActionResult>`, it's enough. The `ProducesResponseType` attribute is used to produce a more descriptive response details for a Swagger page (or for any other tool).

Comment: I tried with `Task<IActionResult>` but it did not work.